# She is not disciplined like me

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

I have a question about ambiguity. This topic often confuses me so I had to ask native English speakers about this. Do you think a sentence like **“She is not disciplined like me”** ambiguous? I think it can be used in either of these two contexts:

- **She is not disciplined and I am not either.**
- **She is not disciplined while I am disciplined myself.**

I think that sentence can be used in either of these contexts, do you agree?

Also I think to be less ambiguous, we could use

- **“She is not disciplined like I am not”**

instead of

- **“She is not disciplined like me.”**

I also wonder if we could say

- **“She is not disciplined unlike me”**

instead of

- **“She is not disciplined like me”**

while I am disciplined myself although I think the version with “like” is probably more common and less stilted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the sentence

> She is not disciplined like me.

is ambiguous. It could be used to mean either of your two cases, but is more often used in the second, to mean:

> She is not disciplined as I am.

Your suggested alternate:

> She is not disciplined like I am not

is awkward, and a fluent speaker would be unlikely to say it, and less likely to write it. Do not use such a construction.

Answer (score 1):

While I see the point of your question,

> She is not disciplined like me

isn't really ambiguous. It means I am disciplined and she is not.

If you change the order, the meaning changes:

> Like me, she is not disciplined.

That means neither of us is disciplined.

If you don't want the meaning to change, you typically have to use **unlike**:

> Unlike me, she is not disciplined.

But that particular sentence uses two negatives and is awkward and confusing, so I would look for a different way of saying the same thing:

> Unlike me, she is rowdy and out of control.

Comment: Do you agree with Mari Lou that “She is not disciplined like I am” or “She is not disciplined like I am not” is wrong/awkward?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the misunderstandings can be resolved by considering the context. These statements are rarely made in isolation. If there is any chance of confusion or ambiguity then maybe you should completely rephrase the sentence.

> Neither she nor I are disciplined
> We are both undisciplined

or

> Unlike me, she is not disciplined
> I am disciplined while / but she is not.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Mea culpa. I should have pointed that out in my answer.

Comment: How about saying “She is not disciplined unlike me” instead of “Unlike me, she is not disciplined”? Is that structure wrong in your opinion?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Will that do?

Comment: @FireandIce Yes, I think they are equivalent, but I'd still include a comma after "disciplined".

Comment: @PeterJennings Thanks. What do you think about “She is not disciplined like I am not”? Mari-Lou claimed it is wrong. Do you agree with her? If yes, can you please explain why so?

Answer (score 0):

She is not disciplined *like me.*

*Is often used, in common spoken English,  to express*:

She is not disciplined like I am (disciplined).

*The ambiguity comes from the fact that the sample sentence can also be read as*:

- She is not disciplined, like me.
  OR
- Like me, she is not disciplined.

That is, I am also not disciplined.